# How can I get the indexes of elements in a Haskell list

Tags: haskell

Is there any function in Haskell that returns the indexs of elements like `elemIndex` in a list. For example for the list `[1,2,3,4,2,3]`, looking for `2` returns `[1,4]`.

Comment: `findIndices (==2) [1,2,3,4,2,3]` https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.2.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v%3AfindIndices

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always use [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?) for this type of questions. Basically, you get the type of the function you're looking for -- in our case you have a list `[a]` and an `a` to search for and want a return of `[Int]` for the indices -- and just [search for it](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5Ba%5D+-%3E+a+-%3E+%5BInt%5D) (in your case, the first result, `elemIndices`, seems to work)